# Why disposed the ObjectContext instance?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

can someone help me here, why I get the exception "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." in the following section?

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy)
    {
        if (this.CheckAccess(this.OnCanRead))
        {
            try
            {
                Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> baseFilter = this.GetFilter(this.OnFilter);

                IQueryable<TEntity> result = this.Set.AsQueryable();

                if (baseFilter != null)
                {
                    result = result.Where(baseFilter);
                }

                if (filter != null)
                {
                    result = result.Where(filter);
                }

                if (orderBy == null)
                {
                    return result.ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    return orderBy(result).ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AccessException("CanRead");
        }
    }
```

Before calling the following point still exists the ObjectContext:

```
                if (baseFilter != null)
                {
                    result = result.Where(baseFilter);
                }

                if (filter != null)
                {
                    result = result.Where(filter);
                }
```

Why no longer?

**- EDIT -**

More Informations:

Here the class using the function where the problem occurs:
[DbContextRepository](http://entityframeworkext.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16211#382544)

In my program, there is a class called ShopRepository, which is derived from:

```
public class ShopRepository : DbContextRepository<Shop>
```

Furthermore, there is a DataManager in my program what the problematic function is called:

```
public static class DataManager
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Initializer.Initializer.SetInitializer();

        ObjectFactory.Configure(
           x =>
           {
               x.For<DbContext>().Use<DataContext>();
               x.For<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().Use<DbContextUnitOfWorkFactory>();
           }
        );

        DbContextUnitOfWorkFactory.SetDbContext(CreateContext);
    }

    private static DbContext CreateContext()
    {
        return new DataContext();
    }

    private static ShopRepository _shops;

    public static ShopRepository Shops
    {
        get
        {
            if (DataManager._shops == null)
            {
                DataManager._shops = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ShopRepository>();
            }

            return DataManager._shops;
        }
    }
```

**- EDIT -**

I have found the problem, but I do not know how to fix it. 
If in the ShopRepository the event OnFilter a dynamic value is returned, such as

```
x => x.InstallationId == InstallationRepository.CurrentInstallationId
```

then error occurs, if there a fixed value such as

```
x => x.InstallationId == 1
```

is returned, no error occurs.

Comment: why all this `try-catch` obfuscation? Makes your code difficult to read.

Comment: What is the context? E.g. where are you instantiating your ObjectContext?

Comment: the try - catch blocks come therefore that it should be used only if it is necessary,does speed reasons.The set is a DbSet<TEntity> object and the included context is a DbContext object.

Comment: that does not make sense. You should remove the try-catch everywhere. Also, show the code that calls this function, that is what I mean by giving more context.

Comment: Okay, the try-catch part once I've implemented. Please look for more information at "-Edit-"

Comment: If **ever** you find yourself writing `catch (Exception)` or `catch (Exception ex)` then you **are doing something wrong**.

Comment: Hey,I still once a little around tried and tested. It is located solely on the following block and not the IQueryable block:

                    if (baseFilter != null)
                    {
                        result = result.Where(baseFilter);
                    }

                    if (filter != null)
                    {
                        result = result.Where(filter);
                    }

But why is disposed there of the ObjectContext.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you dispose of DbContext before enumerating the result of the query. Is is not in the code you provided, but this is the only explanation.

Comment: This was also my first consideration, that's why I call all dispose away. In addition, the ObjectContext only for the variable "result" is disposed not for "this.Set". This happens only in the code by the where function, there are no problems in the block of orderBy.

Comment: So before you call where the context is still not "disposed" after the call, he is "disposed", in between, nothing else happens.

Comment: Linq methods like Where, OrderBy etc will never cause this exception. Only enumerating the result will, in your case ToList() (it may also be ToArray() or any foreach loop that iterates over results of this query).

Comment: See yourself here: 
[Before call Where()](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yi51z.png)
[After call Where()](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HovSf.png)
[BaseFilter](http://i.stack.imgur.com/znGQG.png)

Comment: Does it work when you don't pass in 'where' filter? If so, what does the 'where' filter looks like?

Comment: The base filter includes the expression "x => x.InstallationId == InstallationRepository.CurrentInstallationId".
If I swap the BaseFilter against "x => x != null" but there are no problems.

Comment: I have found the problem, but I do not know how to fix it. 
If in the ShopRepository the event OnFilter a dynamic value is returned, such as "x => x.InstallationId == InstallationRepository.CurrentInstallationId" then error occurs, if there a fixed value such as "x => x.InstallationId == 1" is returned, no error occurs.

Comment: Okay, I have the problem-solving.The problem was that in the Assembly who value InstallationRepository.CurrentInstallationId is not available. Therefore I have now changed the event handling for the OnFilter event so that in the EventArgs the value true/false is returned depending on whether the entity should or not be filtered out.

If someone would like to look at the changes under ["Codeplex Changeset"](http://entityframeworkext.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/16214) these can be found.